# VS2012 How to set output directory for C#'s AnyCPU configuration to x86 and x64 folders for respective solution configs?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, output, anycpu

I have a solution which contains two C++ and two C# projects. For the solution I have a Win32 configuration, which has the two C++ files as `Win32` and the two C# files as `AnyCPU`. The x64 solution has C++ as `x64` and C# as `AnyCPU`.

For the Win32 solution, the C++ files build in the `/x86/Release/` folder, and I've set the C# files to output to the same folder. However, because it's set to `AnyCPU`, the x64 solution also has C# output to the `/x84/Release/` folder.

I was hoping there would be some kind of macro in VS2012 that would allow me to select the solution's configuration so that I could set the output to `$(SolnConfig)/Release`, but there doesn't seem to be anything of the sort.

Is there any way I could (relatively) directly set the output for `AnyCPU` to x86 and x64 directories for respective solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom config and define individual output directories per project under that config.
Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details on how to set it up.

You can then make a batch file that will place bins according to some custom logic like so :

```
set msBuildExe=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe

set configName=%1

set pluginReportsDir=..\..\..\..\Wcf\Plugins\PluginReports

echo ---
echo Backup common PluginReports reports
rem Since this is a post build event, the Common PluginReports is already built
echo ---------------------------
robocopy %pluginReportsDir%\bin\%configName%\ %pluginReportsDir%\bin\ PluginReports.dll PluginReports.pdb

echo ---
echo PluginReports for Site 3
echo ---------------------------
call %msBuildExe% %pluginReportsDir%\PluginReports.csproj /p:Configuration=%configName%Plugins_Site3 /t:Rebuild /noconsolelogger
move /y %pluginReportsDir%\bin\%configName%\PluginReports.dll %pluginReportsDir%\bin\PluginReports_Site3.dll
move /y %pluginReportsDir%\bin\%configName%\PluginReports.pdb %pluginReportsDir%\bin\PluginReports_Site3.pdb
```

Specify the batch file as a post build event and it will copy the files over. It can also perform the over builds if needs be.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are three platform settings: Solution Platform, Project Platform, and Platform Target. I was trying to set AnyCPU from the Project Platform level, which caused the mix-up for having the same output directory for Win32 and x64 in the Solution Platform level.

Answer: set solution platform to Win32 and project platform to x86 from configuration manager, and set Platform Target for the C# files to AnyCPU from the project's properties. Repeat for x64.